# How does a bikerider turn by leaning on one side?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, velocity, vectors

I am trying to understand the following image:
[image]

Could someone please help me understnding it. What I understood so far:
Your angular velocity mutyplied by the impulse gives you the impulsemoment. By applying the right hand rule, you know the impulsemoment-vector is oriented to the left.

When you lean to the left the normal force and gravity force combined create a torque which is a pure moment. The vector of this moment is oriented to the rear of the bike (applied the right hand rule).

I think -and hope- so far my explanation is correct.
However when I apply it to a real situation it gives quite strange results:

on the first image it seems even as if you go backwards and turn to the left, in stead of going straigh forward and turning to the left. And the second image yhea... seems completely proposturous

Comment: Q: Are you asking why a bike rider _must_ lean into the turn? or are you asking how can a bike rider _initiate_ a turn by leaning?  They are two different questons, and the second one is more complicated and somewhat controversial.

Comment: yes it s the second one I am asking.

Comment: @jameslarge : my question has indeed been answered partially on the other thread. But I still remain with this question (which was not really answered there neither). what causes the wheel to turn when you lean?

And why is this interpretation incorrect: http://imgur.com/bsCUhyC ?

Comment: I'm not a physicist, just a lurker here, but I believe it has something to do with parameters called _rake_ and _trail_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry